# multiple terraform provider versions in local provider directory

Tags: terraform

I wanted to abandon terraform-bundle binary in exchange for recommended solutions described in here https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/tree/main/tools/terraform-bundle (we are upgrading terraform to version 1.x atm)

but I’m facing problem with specifying multiple versions of the same provider. In past our code looked like this (when using terraform-bundle):

tf-bundle.hcl:

```
terraform {
  version = "0.14.11"
}

providers {
  aws = {
    source   = "hashicorp/aws"
    versions = [""3.75.0", "3.75.2"]
  }
```

and we were able to simply run terraform-bundle and we have two versions of aws provider saved locally. However, it seems like it is not possible with terraform providers mirror command.. How can I store it locally and not to use `terrafom-bundle` binary?

Comment: You didn't post any references. It's just text instead of a URL.

Comment: sorry yes, corrected

Comment: Ignoring the syntax error in the `versions` argument `list` value, why not just `~> 3.75`? If a module is locking to a patch version, then that is a very strange anti-pattern that would increase stability and security issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single Terraform configuration can only depend on one version of each provider at a time. There is no syntax for specifying multiple versions.

I'm assuming that you're trying to use `terraform providers mirror` to populate a mirror directory.

That command is designed to work with one configuration at a time and mirror the exact dependencies currently required for that configuration. You can run it multiple times in different working directories with the same target directory to mirror potentially many versions of the same provider, but each single configuration can only possibly contribute one version of each provider.

```
cd config1
terraform providers mirror ~/.terraform.d/plugins
cd ../config2
terraform providers mirror ~/.terraform.d/plugins
```

The second call to `terraform providers mirror` will update `~/.terraform.d/plugins` to include additional provider packages if needed, while preserving the ones that were placed there by the first call.

---

If your goal is only to create a local directory to use as a "filesystem mirror" then you don't need the metadata JSON files that `terraform providers mirror` generates, since those are only for [network mirrors](https://www.terraform.io/internals/provider-network-mirror-protocol).

In that case, the only requirement is to match one of [the two supported directory structures](https://www.terraform.io/cli/config/config-file#filesystem_mirror), and so you can potentially construct such a directory without Terraform's help:

```
mkdir ~/.terraform.d/plugins
cd ~/.terraform.d/plugins
mkdir -p registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/3.75.0/linux_amd64
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-aws/3.75.0/terraform-provider-aws_3.75.0_linux_amd64.zip
unzip terraform-provider-aws_3.75.0_linux_amd64.zip -d registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/3.75.0/linux_amd64
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-aws/3.75.2/terraform-provider-aws_3.75.2_linux_amd64.zip
unzip terraform-provider-aws_3.75.2_linux_amd64.zip -d registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/3.75.2/linux_amd64
```

After running the above commands, the `~/.terraform.d/plugins` directory will contain two specific versions of the AWS provider. That is one of the [implied local mirror directories](https://www.terraform.io/cli/config/config-file#implied-local-mirror-directories), so unless you've overridden this behavior with a custom `provider_installation` block in your CLI configuration Terraform should then install that provider only from this local directory and not from the origin registry.

(I've assumed that you are using Linux above; if not then the details will be slightly different but the effect still the same. Specifically, you'll need to use the correct platform name instead of `linux_amd64` in the directory paths and URLs; you can see the platform name for your current platform by running `terraform version`.)